# Plotting timeseries in interactively in R or Python

Tags: python, r, interactive

I have a long timeseries of many variables. I want to plot this interactively in one graph with secondary axes so the we can zoom and check the value in either in second/minutes time scale to yearly preferably in R. Dataset has recorded every 15 minutes.  I was able to make a zoomable graph for only one variable in R. See attached file. any better solution if we could plot the time series with multiple plots with spitting a plot window f.eks?
thanks in advance!

Comment: The plotly package is a quite good quite good choice for this. (available for both R and Python). You can create plots, that look like this: https://plotly-r.com/interactives/linetypes.html   - It is zoomable and you can add secondary axes if you want to.

Comment: That looks great. is it possible to divide plotting space in more boxes also. great if i could get the sample code for the plot you refered:-)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `highcharter` package to provide time-series highcharts like this one (but with more variables):
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series

To provide this chart in R, you need to convert your data to a 2-column matrix. First column is the time difference between your time data with Jan 01, 1970 in milliseconds, the second column is your variable. A sample demo in R looks like this:

```
matrixdate <- function(df, col) {
  df <- df[, c("date", col)]
  df$date <- difftime(df$date, as.Date("1970-01-01", tz= ""), units = "secs") * 1000 # notice the time-zone
  df <- data.matrix(df)
}
hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(zoomType = "x") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime") %>%
  hc_add_series(type = "line",
                name = "Mean",
                data = matrixdate(df, "mean")) %>%
  hc_add_series(type = "line",
                name = "Median",
                data = matrixdate(df, "median")) 
hc
```

This is how I do it until now. I don't know if there's a better way to do it. I don't use the `plotly` package because the `highcharter` package has some advantages over it.
This is a very basic example but you can customize all chart elements like axises, legend, label, tooltip (popup appears when you hover a point),...

Addtional references:

https://jkunst.com/highcharter/index.html

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/

Comment: Nice, didn't know the highcharter package at all till now. Looks like a decent plotly alternative.

Answer (score 0):

An example how to do these things with plotly (taken from their hp):

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

top5 <- txhousing %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  summarise(m = mean(sales, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(desc(m)) %>%
  top_n(5)

tx5 <- semi_join(txhousing, top5, by = "city")

plot_ly(tx5, x = ~date, y = ~median) %>%
  add_lines(linetype = ~city)
```

Looks this as an interactive plot: https://plotly-r.com/interactives/linetypes.html